# Facebook Graph API Error 200 after requesting comments for a facebook page post

Tags: http, facebook-graph-api, graphql, instagram-graph-api

When I try to get all the comments below a facebook page post using the graph api explorer via

```
GET
https://graph.facebook.com/12.0/{post-id}?fields=comments
```

the answer looks like:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) Missing Permissions",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "fbtrace_id": "AqyOUwmTl...3n5y-Br"
  }
}
```

Why?

In case I just request the post like

```
GET
https://graph.facebook.com/12.0/{post-id}
```

I got back a valid answer:

```
{
  "created_time": "2021-12-21T10:05:40+0000",
  "message": "This is a test post.",
  "id": "x0xxxxxxxxxx95_1xxxxxxxxx74"
}
```

This is kinda strange because I request these datas with an admin user of the facebook page and set the following permissions for the access token:

```
read_insights
pages_show_list
instagram_basic
publish_to_groups
pages_read_engagement
pages_read_user_content
pages_manage_posts
public_profile
```

Appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: Can't reproduce that. Does this happen for all posts, or just specific ones?

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for the effort. Yes, this happens for every post from the facebook page.

Comment: Are you using the admin user token, or a page token?

Comment: @CBroe What is the difference between those tokens? When I try to generate an access token after I selected my facebook page in "User or Page", a pop up needs to be confirmed with my admin user and after that "User-Token" is shown in the "User or Page" bar.

Comment: Hell yeah, it works with a page access token! I had to request one via the user token. You can post it as answer if you want. I will accept this after. Thank you!

Comment: I had the same problem. It seems a bit weird that I can access a page post, but not the comments of the same post using a System User Access Token.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of use "User token" you have to use "**Page token**"